# Is there a more efficient way to execute this public sub for formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a public sub that fills in formulas across columns (rows are fixed at 28 rows), but the formulas will always need to be autofilled only until the last cell of data in row 2.

`LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

I have 28 formulas that are imbedded in column B and then need to be filled across however many columns I end up needing, but there has to be a more efficient way to do this in a for/next loop or a case statement, right?

This is what I have, it's not pretty.

```
Public Sub formulas()

    LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").Range(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles")

        .Range("B1").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$M:$M,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B3").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B4").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$B:$B,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B5").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$F:$F,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B6").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$J:$J,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B7").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$X:$X,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B8").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$G:$G,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B9").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$I:$I,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B10").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$Z:$Z,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B13").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AA:$AA,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B14").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AB:$AB,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B15").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AC:$AC,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B16").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AD:$AD,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B17").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AE:$AE,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B18").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AF:$AF,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B19").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AG:$AG,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B20").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AH:$AH,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B21").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AI:$AI,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B22").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AJ:$AJ,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B23").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AK:$AK,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B24").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AL:$AL,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B25").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AM:$AM,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B26").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AN:$AN,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B27").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AO:$AO,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
        .Range("B28").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$AP:$AP,MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""

        .Range("B1:B28").FillRight

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: unrelated to the question, but `$G:$X` and `$AC:$C` seem a bit suspicious compared to the other single column ranges

Comment: @Slai yeah, I need to update that, supposed to be G:G and AC: AC

Comment: You have non-sequential iteration (1,3,4-10, 13-28) that doesn't seem to bear any immediately obvious relationship to the array being searched in the Index function, so that rules out dictionary iteration. You could `CONST` some of your string literals which would make maintenance easier (as you only would need to updated the worksheet name "CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL" in one place, etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm familiar with `CONST` for things like row/columns or static figures, but unfamiliar with how I'd apply that to these formulas. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another possibility. The reason I like it is because it clearly identifies the mapping between the destination cell and the formula target.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoadUpTheFormulas()
    Dim formulaMap As Collection
    Set formulaMap = New Collection

    With formulaMap
        .Add "B1,$M:$M"
        .Add "B3,$A:$A"
        .Add "B4,$B:$B"
        .Add "B5,$F:$F"
        '  ... 
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles")
        Dim lastColumn As Long
        lastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Dim map As Variant
        For Each map In formulaMap
            Dim parts As Variant
            Dim theRange As Range
            Dim theFormula As String
            parts = Split(map, ",")
            Set theRange = .Range(parts(0))
            theFormula = "=IFNA(INDEX(CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!" & parts(1) & _
                         ",MATCH(B$2,CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL!$A:$A,0)),"""") & """""
            theRange.Formula = theFormula
            theRange.AutoFill Destination:=theRange.Resize(1, lastColumn)
        Next map
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for... amazing! One question before I mark it solved, how would I then autofill based on last column of data in row 2?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the `AutoFill`. Do notice, though, that you **must** fully qualify your worksheet references -- in the code above because I'm using the `With` clause, you can just use a dot `.`, but you have to put the `.` in front of all references to the sheet, including `.Cells`, `.Columns.Count`, and `.Range`.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, and I've almost certainly misplaced a quote mark so you'll need to double-check that the resulting formula string is valid/correct, but this is the idea I mentioned above in my comment:

> You have non-sequential iteration (1,3,4-10, 13-28) that doesn't seem to bear any immediately obvious relationship to the array being searched in the Index function, so that rules out dictionary iteration. You could `CONST` some of your string literals which would make maintenance easier (as you only would need to updated the worksheet name `"CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL"` in one place, etc

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub formulas()
Const SHEET_NAME$ = "CM_JOB_PROFILE_EXCEL"
Const MATCH_OPEN$ = "MATCH(B$2,"
Const IFINDEX_OPEN$ = "=IFNA(INDEX("

Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim formulaOpen$
Dim matchFormula$
Dim formulaClose$

LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

formulaOpen = IFINDEX_OPEN & SHEET_NAME & "!"
matchFormula = MATCH_OPEN & "," & SHEET_NAME & "!$A:$A,0)"
formulaClose = "),"""") & """""

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles")

        .Cells(1, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$M:$M," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(3, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$A:$A," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(4, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$B:$B," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(5, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$F:$F," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(6, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$J:$J," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(7, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$X:$X," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(8, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$G:$X," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(9, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$I:$I," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(10, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$Z:$Z," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(13, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AA:$AA," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(14, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AB:$AB," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(15, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AC:$C," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(16, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AD:$AD," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(17, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AE:$AE," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(18, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AF:$AF," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(19, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AG:$AG," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(20, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AH:$AH," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(21, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AI:$AI," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(22, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AJ:$AJ," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(23, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AK:$AK," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(24, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AL:$AL," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(25, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AM:$AM," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(26, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AN:$AN," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(27, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AO:$AO," & matchFormula & formulaClose
        .Cells(28, 2 & LastColumn).Formula = formulaOpen & "$AP:$AP," & matchFormula & formulaClose

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: getting an application defined error once it gets to the first `.cells(1,2....)` part. Does this need to be updated to `.range("....)` or will `.cells` suffice? I need to have these dynamically autofill to last column of data in row 2, so I don't know any other way because the column dimension will always change

Comment: If you're getting an error that major it's almost certainly because the formula is malformed print it out and make sure that the quote marks and commas are all in the right place that's probably my mistake

Comment: went with PeterT's solution, but I really appreciate your input, thank you!

Comment: no problem, i was going to revise mine more towards his solution, but he beat me to it. Cheers